# When is $\overline{d}(A \cap A/2)>0$?

Tags: density-function, additive-combinatorics

Let $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ have $\overline{d}(A):= \limsup_{N\to \infty} \frac{|A\cap \{1,\ldots,N\}|}{N} >2/3$. Is it true that $\overline{d}(A \cap A/2)>0$?

What I can show is that this holds for sets $A$ with upper density at least $3/4$, but my method does not generalize for sets of smaller density. On the other hand, any example I can think of satisfies this property.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Note: Here $A/2 := \{n\in \mathbb{N}: 2n \in A\}$.

Comment: I assume that you have a counterexample for $\overline{d}(A) = 2/3$? Can you show it? And perhaps a sketch of your proof for $\overline{d}(A) \ge 3/4$?